# Can I reposition the ellipses (...) in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to find a way to reposition the ellipses (...) for folded sections in org mode. When I have a structure like this:

```
** TODO Make the word better                             :TAG:...
```

the ellipses show after the tag. Is there a way to make it look like this:

```
** TODO Make the word better...                          :TAG:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In one word: NO

The ellipsis are a sign of "hidden/folded" text. As the text is after the TAG, that is where the ellipsis is positioned.

Comment: Nothing to add - but is there a way to have multiple line header, and if there would be, would the :TAG: be after the first line and the ellipsis after the second?